# fetch won't let me authorize get request

Tags: javascript, json, header, cors, fetch

I'm trying to use fetch over the broswer but it just won't work.

I tried:

```
fetch('https://api-2sizcg3ipa-uc.a.run.app/fats', {
headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password')},
mode:'no-cors'
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => console.log(json));
```

But it gives me two errors:

> GET https://api-2sizcg3ipa-uc.a.run.app/fats net::ERR_ABORTED 403

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
> at fetch.js:5

What am I doing wrong? I works when I do it with curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> ```
> mode:'no-cors'
> ```

This makes `fetch` quietly ignore anything that requires permission via CORS instead of failing with an error.

Sending Authorization headers requires permission via CORS.

So don't say you don't want to use it.

Do, however, say `credentials: 'include'` as you want to send credentials.

Comment: Thank you, I did it because it said.
Access to fetch at 'https://api-2sizcg3ipa-uc.a.run.app/fats' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
But I tried adding an Access-Control-Allow-Origin:'*' and it didn't work either.

Comment: @pete — You need to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin correct (to both the HTTP response to the preflight request and the response to the real request). And note it says **requested resource** (i.e. what you get **from** the server) not the *request* (which is what you send to the server) - it would make the entirely security policy pointless if your JS could give itself permission to access anything it liked.

Comment: I tried adding the credentials:include and 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'https://api-2sizcg3ipa-uc.a.run.app/fats' and it still doesn't work.

Comment: `credentials:'include'` goes on the `fetch` config, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` goes on the response (And if you read the error message you get if you **just** set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` you'll see you need other `Allow-` directives for the specific things you are using)

Comment: on the response? You mean `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` goes on the .then()?

Comment: No. The HTTP response from the server you are trying to read the data from. Your JavaScript cannot give itself permission to read data from other sites.